# Gallery shortcode is empty but magically creates a gallery

Tags: shortcode, gallery, post-content

I have a post with only this `[gallery id="file"]` in text editor but in visual, there appears a gallery. I was moving these posts and updating gallery ids automatically, but these posts don't have any gallery image ids to move or update. I checked the database, I found [gallery id="file"] there in post_content too.

How does this magic work? I need the ids.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the gallery shortcode, when no IDs are given, is to display all images that are attached to the current page/post. An image is attached to a post when it's uploaded directly to a specific post.

Comment: How do I see these ids then? In the database or wordpress?